# Save Button Do nothing and does not work in my backend

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, area

My magento admin area does not save anything, whenever i do any activity either in configuration , editing some code in home page or even re-index , the message shows up like it is saved but its not saving there and just refreshes the page. But if after clicking save, i log out from admin area and again login, changes shows up but then also it does not reflect on my frontend. 
I'm not getting what kind of issue is this and not getting any solution for same.
I m facing this problem for two days now, it was all good till then. 
Some body please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

If changes does not reflect in frontend thend few possibilities could be happen:

1. Compilation is enabled. (Disable compilation **System->Tools->Compilation**)
2. Reindexing is in process (Reindex all **System->Index Management**)
3. Caching is enabled. (Clear all caches **System->Cache Management**)

No other reason is possible as you said it was working two days back.

Comment: All three you mentioned already checked ,but not helping and yes everything was fine two days back. But now its not. I do changes, i click on save button. it shows changes are made in written but doesn't reflect neither in back end nor in front end . and yes one morething, if i then leave it for 3-4 hours. changes reflects. so, in short its taking too long  to reflect changes both in backend and frontend

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Clearing the Cache/Index and Browser Cache is not always enough.  I know this answer is late but to anyone reading this, you have to go into your folder that holds your project and go into your remote/livesite go into your var open your cache and delete all the files in there, they should have names like mage--0... etc. I've had so many problems before where my cache was holding on to data even though I "cleared" the cache in admin.

If your program was running fine before then it's most likely a caching error, I'm pretty positive.